# read and get content from tempfile .xlsx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xlsx, axlsx

I am using `dropzone` to send an `.xlsx` file to my controller, that sends me the file by parameters and I get an `<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fe9f87bb030`

In my controller I am trying to receive and read it but it does not work

```
def update_activities_with_excel
    file = params[:file].tempfile
    File.open(file, 'r') do |file|

    end
end
```

`file` prints:

```
#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20190731-16696-1khug2d.xlsx>
```

My parameters:

```
Parameters: {
"file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fe9f87bb030 
@tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20190731-16696-1khug2d.xlsx>, 
@original_filename="Actividades.xlsx", 
@content_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", 
@headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; 
filename=\"Actividades.xlsx\"\r\n
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet\r\n">}
```

I need to get its content to process it, I am using the `axlsx gem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution using the `creek gem`

```
file = params[:file]
creek = Creek::Book.new file.tempfile
```